# What is the correct response to Googlebot for a search_term_string from site search markup with _escaped_fragment?

Tags: googlebot, escaped-fragment, google-sitelinks-searchbox

I have a AJAX web online-shop with hashbang URL and added SiteLinks as JSON-LD. I follow [this introduction](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox).

```
 {  
      "@context":"http://schema.org",
      "@type":"WebSite",
      "url":"https://example.com#!cat-level-1",
      "potentialAction":{  
         "@type":"SearchAction",
         "target":"https://example.com/#!cat-level-1?search={search_term_string}",
         "query-input":"required name=search_term_string"
      }
   }
```

Our url structure is following:

```
https://example.com#!cat-level-1/cat-level-2/...
```

Now Google calls  `https://example.com?_escaped_fragement_=products?search={search_term_string}`.

We have `_escaped_fragement_` HTML snapshots, but we don't know which response is correct for this Googlebot request.

- HTTP 200 with product not found page?
- HTTP 404?

Comment: Google said that they stopped crawling all HTML snapshots with `_escaped_fragment`: https://searchengineland.com/google-has-deprecated-their-ajax-crawling-scheme-233402

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us what your JSON-LD looks like?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller json-ld added